# ASP.NET MVC - Bailing out of a request in the Controller Constructor? OR how to pick a view on unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where in my controller's constructor, I have some logic that will make this request, die for sure.

Is it possible to somehow invoke an action from the constructor itself, and then stop the Action that was originally going to take place?

Ideally, all I want to do is, call a View from my constructor if a condition is not met, or optionally call another Action which will call a specific view for me.

The idea is, to not write the error checking code in each Action, since all the actions have one basic element to check.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a custom [IControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.aspx) which handles specific exceptions thrown from the constructor?

See [Custom Controller Factory in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.aspx).